# Need help identifying plastic grille

Tags: plastic

I'm trying to figure out what this item (left behind by the previous owner of the house) is. Can anyone help identify it so I can determine whether it should trashed or not?

[image: Photo of a plastic grille]

Comment: Is there any writing on it other than "This side up"?

Comment: Dishwasher? Washing machine? Dryer?

Comment: I just accepted mikes' answer - it was indeed a shelf for the dryer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the clothes  dryer (possibly Kenmore Elite) was included in the sale it may be the shelf unit that allows you to dry sneakers without them banging.

Comment: Thanks. It is indeed the shelf for the dryer (happens to be a Maytag). Your answer helped point me in the right direction (Google search for the user manual).